# IPagedList - Minimal Paging Control w/ Item Count Text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I'm using `PageList.MVC` to show the paging and I wondering how can I show
 `Showing items 99 through 99 of 9999`

I have used this below code but its showing with-in the control:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfData, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page }), PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithItemCountText)
```

What I'm looking is to just show the label that says:
`Showing items 99 through 99 of 9999`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing that will print just that for you. You'll have to construct the text yourself using the data on your `IPagedList` instance:

```
@{ var pagedList = (IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfData; }
<p>
    Showing items
    @((pagedList.PageNumber - 1) * pagedList.PageSize + 1)
    through
    @(pagedList.PageNumber * pagedList.PageSize)
    of
    @pagedList.TotalItemCount
</p>
```